# The usage of Flask-restful routing functions is correct?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I can access  `/v1/folder` but cannot access  `/v1/folder/<folder-id>`. Could you tell me the reason? In the [flask-request document](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing) said `add_resource()` can route multiple URI. But I cannot. Maybe I misunderstand something. Please tell me if you find the clue.

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource, abort

class Folder(Resource):
  def post(self, folder_id):
      return { "message":"post with folder_id"}, 200


  def post(self):
      return { "message":"post without folder_id"}, 201



app = Flask(__name__)

.....

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp, serve_challenge_on_401=True)
api.add_resource( Folder, '/v1/folder', '/v1/folder/<string:folder_id>')
app.register_blueprint(api_bp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True )
```

The error messages is "TypeError: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder_id' ". What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not support function/method overloading, so the `post` method you declared last is always going to be the one that's used. Instead, you should use the tools Python does provide - default values for arguments.

I would personally do the following:

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource, abort

class Folder(Resource):
  def post(self, folder_id=None):
      if folder_id is None:
          return self.__simple_post()
      else:
          return self.__parameter_post(folder_id)

  def __parameter_post(self, folder_id):
      return { "message":"post with folder_id"}, 200

  def __simple_post(self):
      return { "message":"post without folder_id"}, 201



app = Flask(__name__)

.....

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp, serve_challenge_on_401=True)
api.add_resource( Folder, '/v1/folder', '/v1/folder/<string:folder_id>')
app.register_blueprint(api_bp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True )
```

Or you could handle the logic in the `post` method, if the logic is similar enough and not too long. If the logic ends up being unreadable, though, consider using the approach I suggested.

Comment: You are very welcome. I actually had to do this a few days ago myself, so I still remember how I handled it.